# The terminal process failed to launch in VSCode (macOS)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

When attempting to run/debug [my VSCode extension](https://github.com/bradydowling/auto-coder), I'm getting the following error:

```
The terminal process "/usr/local/bin/zsh '-c', 'npm run watch'" failed to launch (exit code: 127).
```

I have set `terminal.integrated.shell.osx` to my zsh location in settings but it’s still failing for some reason. When I run `/usr/local/bin/zsh '-c', 'npm run watch'` from iTerm it runs fine.

How can I fix this error?

I'm also wondering if this is the reason all my breakpoints are unbound when I set them.

[image: unbound breakpoint in VSCode]